# Server certificate used as CA cert, why does it work?

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I helped my organization configured a web server with HTTPS connection using a signed cert from a well known public CA.

All other devices could access that web server through browser. The certificate is verified by the browser. Good sign.

However, when I'm testing the web server's REST api endpoints via cURL, I received this error message:

**curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

After some research, I supplied my signed server cert via --cacert to my curl command, and the problem was gone.

```
curl https://abc.example.com/api/v1/get_something --cacert signed_server_cert.pem
```

I also tried to use download the cert via Chrome (by clicking on the padlock icon), and fed that cert to my curl command, still worked. The downloaded certificate file has two more certs in the .crt file than my original signed server cert.

My question here is, why the signed server cert can be served as a "CA Cert" to the curl command? I thought the error message was telling me "Hey I don't know who your CA is so I cannot verify the cert" but in my case I didn't really provide the CA cert.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.
Ask instead on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

Normally `--cacert` requires certificates which are a root CA, i.e. certificate is its own issuer and has the basic constraints CA:true. With the [X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags.html) flag though it is possible to end the trust chain in a certificate which is not self-signed (but trusted). As a special case with a trust path of zero length on also can give the server certificate itself, even if it is not a CA certificate. This option is enabled by default in curl since version 7.68.0 if build with OpenSSL as the TLS backend.